# Isomorphism $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, tensor-products

I need to prove that the map, defined on the simple tensors as $$ z \otimes w \longmapsto (zw,z\overline{w}) $$ and then extended by linearity, is an isomorphism. I understand how it is a ring homomorphism, its surjectivity and the injectivity on simple tensors. Anyway I cannot find a way to prove it for the sum of tensors.

Comment: The map is $\Bbb{R}$-linear and both sides have dimension $4$ over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually you're right, I don't know why I didn't think of that! Maybe I was too caught in the ring structure and forgot the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space one. Thank you!

Comment: if I get it correct, you need to prove either injectivity or surjectivity, while only the injectivity is "obvious".

Comment: @PeterFranek:  Over $\Bbb{R}$ left hand side has basis $(1\otimes 1, 1\otimes i, i\otimes 1, i\otimes i)$.  RHS has basis $((1, 0), (i, 0), (0, 1), (0, i))$.  Left hand basis maps to $((1, 1), (i, -i), (i, i), (-1, 1))$ - not too difficult to show this is also a basis of RHS.

Comment: @JohnDoe your comments seem to comprise an answer.